# Couchdb: logging in index view for fulltext search don't work(lucene). Why?

Tags: view, lucene, couchdb, logging

I use example from here -  https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene

```
// log an event (trace, debug, info, warn and error are available) 
if (doc.foo) {   log.info("doc has foo property!"); }
```

but logging in my code don't work

```
{
   "_id": "_design/record",
   "_rev": "68-1c6abdda5fce77d0cc14f12d84c4f2f4",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "list": {
           "map": "function(doc){\nemit(doc._id, doc);\n}"
       }
   },
   "shows": null,
   "lists": null,
   "fulltext": {
       "all": {
           "index": "function(doc){var ret=new Document();log.info('test test test');return ret}"
       }
   }
}
```

if use log('test ...') instead log.info('test'), request exceeds timeout 10 sec.

But log('test') worked in map function:

```
function(doc) {
  log('log work!');
  emit(null, doc);
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, it works fine here (0.8.0). Also, "map" functions are couchdb, which has a different logging API to couchdb-lucene.

Answer (score 0):

One wild guess is that you're looking in couchdb.log and not couchdb-lucene.log (where the output goes).

Comment: I have v1.0.1, couchdb-lucene.log last changed a month ago. I set permissons on all folders  - 777. May be need enable log?

Comment: function(doc){var ret=new Document();ret.add(doc.name);ret.add(doc.description);log.info('test test test');return ret} - here search working, logging - no

Comment: That should work. a) are you adding new docs? b) are you logging at INFO level (check log4j.xml), try log.warn('test test test') instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found several files on the server and logs were written here /logs/couchdb-lucene.log

```
root@GENSTAGE01:/srv/couchdb-lucene/conf# find / -name log4j.xml
/srv/couchdb-lucene/conf/log4j.xml
/root/couchdb-lucene/target/test-classes/log4j.xml
/root/couchdb-lucene/target/classes/log4j.xml
/root/couchdb-lucene/src/main/resources/log4j.xml
/root/couchdb-lucene/src/test/resources/log4j.xml

root@GENSTAGE01:/srv/couchdb-lucene/conf# find / -name couchdb-lucene.log
/srv/couchdb-lucene/logs/couchdb-lucene.log
/logs/couchdb-lucene.log
```

**Robert Newson, thank you!**